# Can't read the file from internal storage (file doesn't exist issue)

Tags: android, memory, bluetooth, storage, internal

I have a routed device and when I do this

```
adb shell  cat /data/misc/bluetooth/dynamic_auto_pairing.conf
```

it prints the content of this file.

But in my code when I write something like this, it says that the file does not exist. Well from the console I see it I know is there, but from code I can't read it. My question is what is the problem , am I missing some permission or what is the problem ? can someone provide me with some code to read the content from this file.

Thanks

```
File pa = new File("/data/misc/bluetooth/","dynamic_auto_pairing.conf");
//this doesn't works also
//File pa = new File("/data/misc/bluetooth","dynamic_auto_pairing.conf");
//File pa = new File("/data/misc/bluetooth/dynamic_auto_pairing.conf");
if(pa.exists()){
    Log.v("tag", "does exists");
}else{
    Log.v("tag", "does NOT exist");
}
```

Comment: Did U add following permissions to your application:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

Comment: I do not try to access the blue-tooth, I just want to read file from the memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is on sdcard, try:

```
File pa = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/data/misc/bluetooth/dynamic_auto_pairing.conf");
```

Also try to add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

outside `<application></application>` in your manifest file.

**EDIT**
If the file is in internal memory: Your app can read only from a special folder in internal memory. The path to that folder is returned by:
    getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()

So put the file there and read it with `openFileInput()`.

More info:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: sorry , doesn't works :(, does anybody read the content from any of the /data/misc/ files ?

Comment: Is `/data/`folder on the root of the phone memory, or sdcard? If it is on the root of phone memory your application cannot access it. Put it on sdcard.

Comment: it is on the internal storage on the phone that is the problem. Is it possible to read this file ?, and if not is there any workarounds ?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs for `File`...

> public File (String dirPath, String name)
>
> Constructs a new File using the specified directory path and file name, **placing a path separator between the two.**

In your code you are using...

```
File pa = new File("/data/misc/bluetooth/","dynamic_auto_pairing.conf");
```

...and because your `dirPath` ends with a separator `"/data/misc/bluetooth/"` it will result in two separators. In other words, effective path will be...

> /data/misc/bluetooth//dynamic_auto_pairing.conf

Note the `//` after 'bluetooth`

Comment: Have you even managed to read the content form file placed in /data/misc/ folder ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android 6.0 or higher. You must request permission in code.